# How to access a member of object whose member name (or path) is stored in a string? (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I have an object and a string variable as below -

```
var obj={"person":{"phone":{"home":123456}}};
var acccessString="person.phone.home";
```

In html, I need to display the `obj.person.phone.home` value using the accessString. I have tried to do the below but it doesn't work -

```
{{obj.{{acccessString}}}}
```

Please suggest a way to access a member of object whose member name (or path) is stored in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Angular's [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service

```
var getter = $parse(accessString);
var value = getter(obj);
```